# MySQL reduce varchar index size?

Tags: mysql

I have a table with a `varchar(255)` column. I perform A LOT of searches based on this column, so I need fast `select`s. That's why I used that `varchar` as `primary key`, but this **doubles** the table's size.

I there any way around this? I understand indexes increase the column size but doubling it is just ridiculous!

Is it possible to store only the 1st 10 bytes of the varchar in the index and sightly increase the select time by heavily reducing the size?

```
CREATE TABLE data_storage(
id TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
data VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
no INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
UNIQUE KEY(id, data), PRIMARY KEY(id, no)) ENGINE = INNODB
```

Comment: Making something a primary key just because you need to search over it makes no sense. Provide more details. PS: when you index over character type columns - you can specify the prefix length.

Comment: Sorry. The table contains 2 ints and 1 varchar. I need to search based on the varchar.

Comment: It's still not enough. Have you checked my "PS" part?

Comment: @zerkms: you can specify the prefix length. ---> How?

Comment: have you checked a documentation http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-index.html ?

Comment: Usually you only make something a primary key if you are going to seek over the data in that order.  Otherwise a standard index over the field or a full text index would be better.

Comment: @Dijkgraa: "Usually you only make something a primary key if you are going to seek over the data in that order" --- wrong again. Is it April 1st today? o_O

Comment: The table you have shown doesn't have a primary key that contains a `varchar`.

Comment: Sorry, it does have one unique key. Also, I like Bleach!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The fact that you make many searches on a column shouldn't be the reason that you're making it a primary key, or that it is in fact a good candidate.

It's not useful to create something like a partially indexed primary key, because of the uniqueness constraint; however, you *can* create a partial index:

```
ALTER TABLE `tablename` ADD INDEX(`colname`(10));
```

Then, either remove the primary key or find a better one, assuming you have no foreign keys pointing to this table.

If you do have foreign keys pointing to this table, it would be best to create a surrogate key, such as an auto incremented integer column.

Comment: "assuming you have to foreign keys pointing to this table" --- even if you don't have FKs, it's still a good idea to have a PK (monotonously growing or decreasing one)